# fadeIn only new data from mysql table not all data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, refresh, fadein

I'm working on this project trying to create a simple site where a user can input information then on a different page that same information is displayed.

I am using JQuery to refresh the page and .load new content, MySQL to store the information, and PHP to insert and retrieve that information.

The problem I am having now is i'm using Javascript to update the page and .fadeIn the data but currently it is just fading out and fading in ALL of the data. What I want it to do is to keep the current data the same and ONLY fade in the new data.

Here is my JQuery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
$("#responsecontainer").fadeOut('fast').load('output.php');
}, 3000);

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

});
</script>
```

Here is my PHP called 'output.php':

```
<?php include_once('db_connect.php'); ?>

<?php include_once('input.php'); ?>

<?php
//query the database
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY ID DESC");

//fetch the results / convert results into an array
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):
$title = $rows['notestitle'];
$text = $rows['notestext'];

?>

<div id="title">
<h1><?php echo "$title<br>"; ?></h1>
</div>
<div id="text">
<h2><?php echo "$text<br>"; ?></h2>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And here is the code for the page that is displaying the info:

```
<?php include_once('db_connect.php'); ?>

<?php include_once('input.php'); ?>

<div id="header"></div>

<div id="responsecontainer">
<?php include_once('output.php'); ?>
</div>
```

Let me know if you need me to provide anything else or if something is unclear to you.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You query selects all the data. SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY ID DESC will return all the data on the table NOT new rows. However I dont think this is a MySQL question. More jQuery perhaps.

Comment: I need to be able to select all of the data. That is why I have the jQuery to refresh the page so it will automatically add new data. The refresh is working fine but I want to be able to fadeIn only the new data, currently it's fading all data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this simple query with limit

```
SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The LIMIT 1 is only limiting the results to the latest row, I still need to be able to show all the rows.

Comment: Any other ideas dealing more with the jQuery functions?